# Rails User tracking activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, notifications, tracking

I want to track user activity on site. I tried `ActiveSupport::Notifications` but hasn't `user_id` or something to define a user. As I see, there are 2 ways to do this: through ActiveRecord queries, and through Page Requests. In the first case I should subscribe to all possible user actions with model (`after_create`, `after_destroy` etc.), and I have about 20 associated models, that is a lot of duplicate code. The second - I don't know how to do this, but it's seems simply to me.
I'm not using Device or any gem.

Perhaps in the first way, I could include module and make all logic in it, but It's not working.

Comment: Hi @Alder, what kind of activities you want to track ?

Comment: Hi, sameera207. For example, user create community, user invite person to it. But all of it depends on db crud operations on the belongs to user models.

Comment: this should do the trick [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) ;) HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `before_filter :track_activity` in `ApplicationController`, ti calls every time when user enter any page.